# GIMP Script.Fu script to batch convert JPEG to PNG

Tags: batch-processing, gimp, script-fu

Can someone give me the script I would need to run to batch convert many *.jpeg files to *.png in Script.Fu in GIMP?

Currently I am spending way too much time manually exporting every image and it's a waste of time.

I can't install anything right now so can't use alternative applications.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alright, after a lot of trials and errors I finally figured out how to convert one file format to another using only GIMP.

This is the Script-Fu script for conversion to PNG:

```
(
    let* ((filename "{{filename}}")
            (output "{{output}}")
            (image (car (gimp-file-load 1 filename filename)))
            (drawable (car (gimp-image-get-active-layer image))))
    (file-png-save-defaults 1 image drawable output output)
)
```

Where `{{filename}}` is input file that needs to be converted (a jpeg file, for example), `{{output}}` is the output file that you need (it can be simply the same file name but with PNG extension)

How to run it: *it can probably be improved*

```
gimp -i -n -f -d --batch "{{one-line script-fu}}"
```

More about command line options you can find in [GIMP online documentation](https://docs.gimp.org/en/gimp-fire-up.html).

The place that needs to be changed is `{{one-line script-fu}}` and it has to be... one-line! You can *probably* do all of this in one file using cmd (in case if you use Windows), but for me it was easier to use Python, so here's the script for it:

```
import subprocess, os

def convert_to_png(file_dds):
    #Loads the command to run gimp cli (second code block)
    #Note: remove "{{one-line script-fu}}" and leave one space after the --batch
    with open("gimp-convert.bat", "r") as f:
        main_script = f.read()

    #Prepares the Script-Fu script to be run, replacing necessary file names and makes it one-line (the firs code block)
    with open("gimp-convert-png.fu", "r") as f:
        script = f.read().replace("\n", " ").replace("{{filename}}", file_dds) \
            .replace("{{output}}", file_dds[:-3]+"PNG").replace("\\", "\\\\").replace("\"", "\\\"")

    subprocess.run(main_script + " \"" + script + "\" --batch \"(gimp-quit 1)\"",
        cwd = os.getcwd(),
        shell = True)
```

And you should get your file converted to PNG!

I needed this for my texture upscale project, all of the code below you can find [here](https://github.com/OSA413/Sonic4_ModLoader_examples/tree/master/examples/upscale_template).

Tested with GIMP 2.10

Comment: With ImageMagick this would be just 'magick convert *.psd -set filename:base "%[basename]" "%[filename:base].png"`.

Comment: @xenoid I know but ImageMagick couldn't convert DDS file with alpha channel to PNG properly so I went all the way to figure out how to automate conversion with GIMP.

Comment: Yes but your question is about JPG to PNG, not DDS to PNG. So people coming here could be misled into the complicated Gimp-based solution when a much simpler one exists. Your answer is also more complicated than necessary, it reads two external files (whose contents are not described) when the script-fu could be a string in the Python code, and not a separate file, and use Python3 f-strings.

Answer (score 0):

The real solution is to use ImageMagicks convert, as simple as `magick convert some.jpeg some.png`. There must be a "portable" version somewhere that you can use off a USB key.

Otherwise with Gimp, a much less manual way that doesn't need for a new script, since it uses an existing script:

- get/install [ofn-export-layers](https://sourceforge.net/projects/gimp-tools/files/scripts/)
- `File>Open` the first JPEG
- `File>Open as layers` more Jpegs. You can select several/all jpegs in one call (actual number limited by available RAM mostly). Once this is done you have many Jpegs stacked in the same image
- `File>Export all layers`, making sure the name pattern you use ends in `.png` (the doc that comes with the script explains how that works).

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately this did not help me as I needed to be able to save all the files with their original file names. These names have to be perfect and I certainly don't want to type them in. I will look into a portable version of ImageMagicks but since my usage is being monitored I don't really want to cause trouble so GIMP would be preferable

Comment: With `File>Open as layers` the layers are named after their source image. In `ofn-export-layers`, you set the save pattern to `{name}.png` to have the layers saved  with their layer/source name in which `jpg` is replaced by `png`. In other words: file `covfefe.jpg` is loaded as a layer named `covfefe.jpg` which ofn-export-layers will save as `covfefe.png` in a directory of your choice. (*) Use the version updated today (v0.1), the `{name}` parameter acted a bit differently in the previous version. And yes, it saves the images to their initial size, they aren't cropped to the canvas size.

Comment: Thanks. So I had a batch to do again but the script is not appearing in the menu File as it should. Any insight on how to fix this?

Comment: Although it looks like a script, for Gimp it is technically a plugin and so should go in the `plug-ins` directory, not in the `scripts` one. Restart Gimp to have it taken in account.

Comment: Unfortunately I will have to add plugins etc each time I need them but otherwise it works! Thanks so much. The directory selection is clunky and doesn't default to the same directory the files came from but is still better than exporting over and over again.

Comment: I think you can tweak the settings of the Gimp windows shortcut to make it start in a given directory ("working directory"), in this case that would become the default directory to save the files.